# Change default divide by 0 behavior in C++/iOS

Tags: c++, ios, arm, clang, divide-by-zero

I am building an iOS application.

I have the following code:

```
if(pbCB == 0) { //Don't divide by 0
    c = 1;
} else {
    c = sqrt(pb / pbCB) * PROTANOPIA_WBP;
}
```

I really want to get rid of the if statement (the code above is within a for-loop).

I know that doing floating point division by 0 and then casting that value to an unsigned char gives (using gdb to test):

```
//floating-point division by 0
p 10.0/0
$1 = inf

//casted to an unsigned char
p (unsigned char) (10.0/0)
$2 = 0 '\000'
```

What I'm wondering is if there is a way to change the definition of division by 0 so that it returns 1? I was told by a professor that this is a hardware/architecture problem and that there is no way to do it, but I wanted to see if maybe that wasn't the case. Thanks for any answers/thoughts/advise.

Comment: You could use `NSDecimalNumber` and implement your own rounding behaviour returning `1` with [`exceptionDuringOperation:error:leftOperand:rightOperand:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSDecimalNumberBehaviors_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSDecimalNumberBehaviors/exceptionDuringOperation:error:leftOperand:rightOperand:) when performing the division. EDIT: But yes, what Alan said is probably more relevant...!

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of an `if`? What proportion of the input has zero for `pbCB`? If it's low, the conditional test will cost you almost nothing (branch prediction will do the right thing).

Comment: @AlanStokes the check still has to be done every time. This code is within a loop going over every pixel of every frame of a live 720p video feed. pbCB is a calculation from the RGB pixel values, and it will be 0 iff RGB = (0,0,0). It is more than possible that the user could point the camera at a black object.

Comment: @Matt If it's all black the branch prediction will still win ;-). Have you measured this?

Comment: @MatthewHerbst Compared to the division/sqrt operation, the check will  take pretty much no time at all. I doubt that's where your time is going.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I can't get rid of the division. I will eventually do a look-up table for the sqrt. I'm just trying to get every bit of performance that I can.

Comment: @AlanStokes I don't know much about branch prediction - could you recommend how I would go about testing it? Just point at black, point at not black, and then go in-between a few times?

Comment: @Matt The first rule of optimising is to measure. (Actually, the first rule is "don't", the second rule is to measure.) You need some standard images to try your algorithm on, and you need to be able to measure exactly how long the code you are running takes. Then you can try making changes to see what works, or what the cost of individual parts of the computation are.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson An `if` inside a tight loop means you'll negate pipelining benefits anytime branch prediction goes wrong. This can be much, much more costly than `sqrt` or even a few trigonometry calls.

Comment: @Daan I'm aware that branch prediction is an issue, however I'm not sure how you'd calculate sqrt without hardware support in a time that even approaches the 3-4 cycles you'd lose on a missed branch prediction (and then only if the compiler is wrong) Just saying that there are probably bigger targets to optimize (like possibly the lookup table optimization talked about)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I was assuming that these are harware supported FP calculations. If they're actually integral (except for sqrt), then a LUT is indeed the way to go. If it's software FP, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root is claimed to be faster than LUTs (and `x * inv_sqrt(x) == sqrt(x)`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. It's specified by the floating point specification and implemented in the hardware.

Answer (score 2):

Like Alan Stokes mentioned, you cannot efficiently change how a divide-by-zero is handled.

But depending on the semantics and ranges of the values you're working with, it might be possible to lift and/or scale your inputs so that there are no 0's left.

EDIT:
By semantics, I mean the range of values that are actually produced by the camera in question. Many digital camera's are actually unable to produce the full RGB range. If it doesn't, you can use that information to shift your inputs into the desired range.

If you don't have that sort of information, or your camera does indeed produce (0,0,0)-(255,255,255), the other option is to promote your inputs to floats and shift and/or scale as desired in that format. This is going to require a little more computation, but it *might* be less expensive than failed branch predictions. Be sure to measure the effects on representative input samples before making any final decisions.

Comment: All my values are RGB, 0-255 (unsigned char)

Comment: Ideally, you'd want to know the semantics of those values as well. I.e., does pointing the camera at a black object actually produces (0,0,0)? And does pointing the camera at a reasonably bright, white light actually produce (255,255,255)? I'll edit my answer with a bit more info in a minute.